# Editing table content using Javascript given value

Tags: javascript, html

I need help to get started with inserting text into table using javascript. I am unable to touch the html code

Portion of html code for the table :

```html
<table class="selection">  
<tr>
<td><div class='choices' value=0><button class="btnclass" type="button"></button></div></td>
<td><div class='choices' value=1><button class="btnclass" type="button"></button></div></td>
<td><div class='choices' value=2><button class="btnclass" type="button"></button></div></td>
</tr>
    
<tr>
<td><div class='choices' value=3><button class="btnclass" type="button"></button></div></td>
<td><div class='choices' value=4><button class="btnclass" type="button"></button></div></td>
<td><div class='choices' value=5><button class="btnclass" type="button"></button></div></td>
</tr>
    
<tr>
<td><div class='choices' value=6><button class="btnclass" type="button"></button></div></td>
<td><div class='choices' value=7><button class="btnclass" type="button"></button></div></td>
<td><div class='choices' value=8><button class="btnclass" type="button"></button></div></td> 
<tr>
 
</table>
```

Total there are a table of 3 rows 3 columns, indicated by their value.

Im supposed to assign a unique text for each unique value using javascript. For example, in row 1 column 1, i would like the text to be 'apple', row 2 column 2 as 'orange'. Im unable to modify the code above as they are in html. How do i go about it

This html was given as a question so im unable to explain the rationale of the codes as well. But the html are fixed and cant be modified

Comment: please try to clarify what you mean by `"assign a unique text for each unique value"` ~ Incidentally the HTML fragment above is missing the closing `tr` tag

Comment: Also- a `DIV` does not have a `value` attribute so `<div class='choices' value=0>` is invalid

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to set the text of the button in each row and column. You can do this using following JavaScript code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("btnclass")[0].innerHTML="apple";
```

The above code will set the text of the button in row 1, column 1 to "apple". To set the text for the other buttons, you can use the same code. Just change the index from 0 to the index position of the button.

For example for row 2, column 2, the index would be 4.

See the documentation for the [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) function